# java groovy to extract two strings

Tags: java, groovy

I have the following regular expression to find the word called EXTRACT, but I need to find another work called REPLICAT.  So, REPLICAT | EXTRACT. How to do this in one expression.

```
def matcher =  rawTerminalText =~ /(?m)(EXTRACT +RUNNING +)(.*?\w)( +)(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})( +)(.*?\w)( +)(.*?$)/
```

I tried the following, but its not working.

```
def matcher =  rawTerminalText =~ /(?m)((^| )(REPLICAT|EXTRACT)+$ +RUNNING +)(.*?\w)( +)(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})( +)(.*?\w)( +)(.*?$)/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to know only about those given word which is present in the string or not? then uses below regular expression?

```
def rawText=" The Word which i am looking for is, REPLICAT and EXTRACT"
def Word= /^.*\b(REPLICAT|EXTRACT)\b.*$/;
def findWord= (rawText =~ /$Word/);
log.info  findWord.count;

    Output:
    count will return 1: found
    count will return 0:not found
```

Comment: yes I used the below (\b(?:EXTRACT|REPLICAT)\b to get the work done.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a regex testing site, that has explanations on the regex and allows testing with sample text.

I personally like to use this one: https://regex101.com/ as it has very good explanations on the written regex.

------- EDIT -------

I think you have a space character that should not be there. Instead of (REPLICAT | EXTRACT +RUNNING +) use (REPLICAT|EXTRACT +RUNNING +)

----- END EDIT -----

Comment: Yes that is the side where I went initially to create the regex for just finding the word extract it worked but when I wanted to find the word extract or replicat I just used the pipe (I) symbol and its able to show the output in that site but when I use it at java groovy script it does not honor.

Comment: I used the following: (REPLICAT | EXTRACT +RUNNING +)(.*?\w)( +)(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})( +)(.*?\w)( +)(.*?$) It should match REPLICAT or EXTRACT, but its not matching.  If I put just REPLICAT alone it matches.

Comment: I think you have a space character that should not be there. Instead of (REPLICAT | EXTRACT +RUNNING +) use (REPLICAT|EXTRACT +RUNNING +)

Comment: @LinuxTeche - if oyu find one of our answers helpful, please mark it as the answer - the community will benefit from it and the user who answered as well